# Two integers and an operator. Error, not doing what it needs to do in other compiler

Tags: c

The problem here is that it works on vscode but it doesn't in onlinegdb.com. I think there's some error in my code that I overlook but I can't find so I am hoping someone out there would help me out. thank you very much.

btw there's no warning error in onlinegdb.com but when I try to run it, the result is not right so that's the issue.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  
  //This is a FUNCTION PROTOTYPE :)
  int check(char op);
  int calculate(int a, int b, int c);
  char * print_operators(int op);

  int main()
  {
      // create a variable to store the integers.
      int num1,num2;
      // create a variable to store the operator that the user wants to use.
      char operator;

      //prompt for the first integer.
      printf("Enter first Integer: ");
      scanf("%d", &num1);

      // prompt to enter the operator to be used.
      do
      {
      printf("Enter operator, + as sum, - as difference, * as product, / as quotient: ");
      scanf(" %s", &operator);
      }
      // keep prompting the user until he input the correct operator using the check function call.
      while(check(operator) == -1);

      // prompt for the second integer.
      printf("Enter Second Integer: ");
      scanf("%d", &num2);

      // calculate the total result using the calculate function call and store it to a variable called total.
      int total = calculate(num1, num2, check(operator));

      // using the print_operators to know what is the operator being used to store it in variable operators in a string form.
      char * operators = print_operators(check(operator));

      //output of the result.
      printf("The %s is: %d\n", operators, total);

      return 0;
      
  }
  
  
  // this is function definition of check to verify if the input is valid and if it's valid then covert it to integer in an order.
  int check(char op)
  {
      // creating a char array to store the symbol of the operators.
      char operations[] = {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
      // this variable is to be use in a for loop so that I don't need to use a magic number in for-condition.
      int size = sizeof(operations);

      // looping to convert the operator to integer from 0 to 3 and storing the operator in its ordered form.
      // 0 representing +, 1 representing -, 2 representing *, and 3 representing /.
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
          if(op == operations[i])
          {
              return i;
          }
      }

      // else print invalid and return the value of -1 representing its not valid.
      printf("INVALID\n");
      return -1;
  }


  // this function definition of calculating is to calculate the two integers using the operator that is already converted to an integer.
  int calculate(int a, int b, int c)
  {
    // create a variable to store the result of the calculation.
    int equal;

    // if the operator is 0 then do addition.... and so on.............
    if (c == 0)
    {
        equal = a + b;
    }
    else if (c == 1)
    {
        equal = a - b;
    }
    else if (c == 2)
    {
        equal = a * b;
    }
    //else if its not 0, 1, or 2 then its difinitely 3.
    else
    {
        equal = a / b;
    }

    // then return the result.
    return equal;

  }


  /* This function definition of print_operators is to return the operator as a string so that I can use it in print without manually coding it. */
  char * print_operators(int op)
  {
      char * operators[] = { "sum", "difference", "product", "quotient" };
      int size = sizeof(operators);

      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
          if (i == op)
          {
              return operators[i];
          }   
      }

      // Some compiler needs a return value even if it didn't reach so I just did this just in case your compiler is different from mine.
      //although this is not necessary for my compiler, I've checked it in the cloud server, and there's an error if this is not included.
      char * total = "total";
      return total;
  }
  /* Example if I want to output the 1+2 then my output is "The sum is: 3". Notice that the sum is not constant cuz maybe if I what to use subtraction then I want it to output as "The difference is: 1". */
```

Comment: What is the expected result and the result you are getting instead ? Could you please add these informations to your post ?

Comment: `scanf(" %s", &operator);` - `operator` is declared as a `char`.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Do you use a C++ compiler or why the C++ tag?

Comment: In `print_operators` (which, curiously, does not print anything), `sizeof(operators)` does not mean what you think it means - it's not the number of array elements. But why do you *search* for `op`?

Comment: This is clearly C since "operator" is a reserved identifier in C++. Please don't tag both languages unless you're actually asking about both.

Comment: "Some compiler needs a return value" -- *all* compilers need a return value if you have specified that a function returns a value other than `void`. Some compilers, however, may not warn you that you are not returning a value and lead you into undefined behaviour, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `scanf(" %s", &operator);` should be `scanf(" %c", &operator);` operator because you are expecting a single character here, not a string. It can potentially corrupt the stack.

I guess that should fix your issue with onlinegdb.

There are also other issues and possible simplifications. Such as your `print_operators` function which may be written simply as:

```
char *print_operators(int op)
{
    char *operators[] = { "sum", "difference", "product", "quotient" };
    /* sizeof(array) gives the total size of your array in bytes, not the number of elements in your array, so divide it by the size of each element to get num of elements */
    int count = sizeof(operators)/sizeof(char *);

    /* Since you already have the operator converted to a number in your check() function, just use it directly as index here */
    if(op < count)
      return operators[op];
    else
      return "total";
}
```

> "Some compiler needs a return value"

**All** compilers need a return value if you have specified that a function returns a value other than void. Some compilers, however, may not warn you that you are not returning a value and lead you into undefined behaviour, which is not what you want.